# Nice way to check if backbone fetch returns an empty model

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I am using node.js / express and returning an empty object if no data exists on server (i.e.: res.send({}) on the express side).

However, since I am using Backbone myCollection.fetch(....) 
I am still get a model back, only that it's empty.

As in:

```
  _getLines: function () {
  var self = this;
      self.m_linesCollection.fetch({
          success: function (data) {
              $(Elements.FASTERQ_CUSTOMER_LINES).empty();
              if (_.size(data.models["0"].attributes) == 0)
                  return;      
            },
            error: function () {
                log('error loading collection data');
            }
        });
    }
```

as you can see I am doing a dirty check on client side via:

if (_.size(data.models["0"].attributes) == 0)

which works fine... to check if no real models came back, but I am sure there is a better way to check if model is empty, or send something else from server side :/  ?

Just seems so trivial... I must be missing something...

thx,

Sean.

Comment: Why are you returning empty objects? It seems like your back-end  should just return an empty array, instead of an array of empty objects.

Comment: good call, changed to array and fixed it... TX!!!

Comment: Awesome. I've added an answer so we can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference, but the easiest way around this is to have your server return an empty array instead of an array of empty objects.

Answer (score 0):

Marionettejs is an opinionated Backbone framework. In it, they define the utility function:

```
isEmpty: function() {
  return !this.collection || this.collection.length === 0;
},
```

which you would simply add to your view. You could define it in your initialize, as `this.isEmpty`, or by extending into your view

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... }); 
_.extend( MyView, { isEmpty: function() { ... } });
```

If you return an empty array from your server, the length property of your collection will equal zero and your `isEmpty` funtion will return `true`.

Of course, you could just use

```
if (this.collection.length == 0) { ... }
```